# Maven-war-plugin runs other execute (jooq-codegen-maven) as well

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jooq

**Goal**
Within my pom.xml, I want to have a plugin that creates a war from my project. Also, I want a plugin that generates database files for my project.

**Used plugins**
maven-war-plugin and jooq-codegen-maven.

**Problem**
Whenever I start my maven-war-plugin, it also starts my jooq plugin. This means I generate new database classes right before generating my war.  This is a problem, since it can create some nasty errors I cannot track.

**What I tried**
I tried adding  to the jOOQ plugin, but this makes it skip whenever I execute the plugin itself as well. So don't really know how to solve it.

**Pom.xml**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- or whatever version you use -->
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <!-- Add the webapp dir (otherwise web.xml and context.xml are not picked up)  -->
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/webapp</directory>
                    </resource>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/../Angular/dist</directory>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>

                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Plugin for generating jOOQ classes. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jooq-codegen</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <!-- <skip>true</skip> -->
                <jdbc>
                    <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                    <url>${url.database}</url>
                    <user>root</user>
                    <password>rootie</password>
                </jdbc>
                <generator>
                    <!-- Use my own GeneratorStrategy to make naming easier. -->
                    <strategy>
                        <name>com.apon.database.jooq.GeneratorStrategy</name>
                    </strategy>
                    <database>
                        <name>org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase</name>
                        <includes>.*</includes>
                        <!-- <excludes></excludes> -->
                        <inputSchema>taalmaatjes</inputSchema>
                        <!-- Boolean en bytes zijn gek -->
                        <forcedTypes>
                            <forcedType>
                                <name>BOOLEAN</name>
                                <types>tinyint</types>
                            </forcedType>
                        </forcedTypes>
                    </database>
                    <target>
                        <packageName>com.apon.database.generated</packageName>
                        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                    </target>

                    <generate>
                        <pojos>true</pojos>
                        <daos>true</daos>
                        <interfaces>false</interfaces>
                    </generate>
                </generator>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Execution log maven-war-plugin (mvn install)**

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin\java" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\Gebruiker\IdeaProjects\TaalmaatjesWebsite\RestApi "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=61277:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2017.3.4 install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building RestApi 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jooq-codegen-maven:3.10.2:generate (jooq-codegen) @ RestApi ---
[INFO] No <inputCatalog/> was provided. Generating ALL available catalogs instead.
[INFO] License parameters       
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]   Thank you for using jOOQ and jOOQ's code generator
[INFO]                          

<...>

[INFO] Generation finished: taalmaatjes: Total: 479.009ms, +0.111ms
[INFO]                          
[INFO] Removing excess files    
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ RestApi ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) @ RestApi ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ RestApi ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Gebruiker\IdeaProjects\TaalmaatjesWebsite\RestApi\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ RestApi ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ RestApi ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:3.2.0:war (default-war) @ RestApi ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [RestApi] in [C:\Users\Gebruiker\IdeaProjects\TaalmaatjesWebsite\RestApi\target\RestApi-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp webResources [C:\Users\Gebruiker\IdeaProjects\TaalmaatjesWebsite\RestApi/webapp] to [C:\Users\Gebruiker\IdeaProjects\TaalmaatjesWebsite\RestApi\target\RestApi-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Copying webapp webResources [C:\Users\Gebruiker\IdeaProjects\TaalmaatjesWebsite\RestApi/../Angular/dist] to [C:\Users\Gebruiker\IdeaProjects\TaalmaatjesWebsite\RestApi\target\RestApi-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [902 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\Gebruiker\IdeaProjects\TaalmaatjesWebsite\RestApi\target\RestApi-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ RestApi ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Gebruiker\IdeaProjects\TaalmaatjesWebsite\RestApi\target\RestApi-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war to C:\Users\Gebruiker\.m2\repository\com\apon\RestApi\1.0-SNAPSHOT\RestApi-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\Gebruiker\IdeaProjects\TaalmaatjesWebsite\RestApi\pom.xml to C:\Users\Gebruiker\.m2\repository\com\apon\RestApi\1.0-SNAPSHOT\RestApi-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.449 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-08T22:51:26+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/301M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Try adding `<exec..><id>default-jooq</id><phase>none` or such - see the link to duplicate question.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you :)